# getting logs between ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax

I'm communicating via ajax to a php script.

```
<a href="#" onclick="cancella(12)">Delete</a>

function cancella(elem) {
 $.ajax({
    url: 'mypage.php',  
    type: 'POST',
    data: { canc: elem },
    success: deleteHandler,
    error: errorHandler,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

my php page:

```
if (isset($_POST['canc'])) {
   $toCanc = $_POST['canc'];
      $sqlcanc= "DELETE FROM tablename
                 WHERE id = :id";
    try {                                          
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sqlcanc);                                              
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $toCanc, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                 
$stmt->execute(); 
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
}
```

the problem is, when i hit "Delete", nothing happens. How can i know what goes wrong? is there a way to retrieve any kind of response by php or tracking the process?

Comment: yes. Open up chrome developer tools and look at network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern browsers have a developer console, where you can view what's happening with your ajax requests. For example if you're using Chrome on Windows, you can open the console with F12. On the network tab you can see all the requests that have happened after the current page started loading.

However, it quite often happens that all you get as a response to your malfunctioning ajax request is a blank page. This is due the PHP's settings. Make sure to enable error reporting, by placing this at the top of your PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

You'll want to remove that for production though.

Besides that, you should check your web server's error logs for clues as to what's going wrong.